# Error: no rows to aggregate

Tags: r

I'm working on two data frames, the second one, `df2`, is a **single column**, containing the names of the variables, the first one, `df1`, is a multicolumn(more than 1000), containing numeric values for each variable.

```
VAL1 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "BB", "DD", "AA", "DD")
Num1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2) 
Num2 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4) 
Num3 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7) 
df <- data.frame(VAL1, Num1, Num2, Num3)
df1<-df[,-1] 
df2<- df1[1]
```

On `df1` I made the following operations:

```
tot<- colSums(df1,na.rm = TRUE)
prod<- df1/rep(tot,each = nrow(df1))
```

After this operation I united the `df1` and `df2`:

```
df3<-cbind(df2, prod)
```

As last operation I want to aggregate datas by the first column name (val1)

```
agg<- aggregate(. ~  val1, df3, sum)
```

But doing this operation console print the following error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs,mf[-1L],FUN=FUN,...): no rows to aggregate.
```

I controlled `df3` before aggregating, but it is exactly as I wanted it:

```
  Val1  Num1  Num2 ....
  AA      2     3
  AA      1     5
  BB      3     3 
  BB      7     8
  CD      4     5
  ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: Your initial dataset seems to be `df1`.  How did it changed to `df2`?  Please show a small reproducible example.

Comment: @akrun df1 is the multicolumn dataframe, df2 is the single column one. On the first one i made operations, so it got tranformed in rap

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Isn't it because there is "val1" in your formula, but the column is called "Val1" (capitalized vs small "v")?

Comment: No, the name is correct,  in case of different name the erroe would have been `object "value1" not found`

Comment: @akrun  this is a complete sample of what i did:
`VAL1 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "BB", "DD", "AA", "DD")

Num1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2)

Num2 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4)

Num3 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7)

df <- data.frame(VAL1, Num1, Num2, Num3)

df2<- df1[1]

df1<-df[,-1]

tot<- colSums(df1,na.rm = TRUE)

prod<- df1/rep(tot,each=nrow(df1))  

data2<-cbind(df2,prod)

agg<- aggregate(.~ VAL1,data2,sum)`

But in this case works, i have no idea about why  on my bigger df doesn't work

Comment: @Jua' Learn to edit the question body to make clarification and add code.

Comment: Based on the example, you showed, it is working for me without any errors.  I guess you meant `df2 <- df[1]`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, truly no, and i really have no ideas about why if the code is correct...it seems that it does it only when I use 
 `prod<- df1/rep(tot,each = nrow(df1))` with big datas
and then I unify the two df...i tried to add to df3 a row containing in the first column `"tot"` and in the following the `colSums` values.....in this case aggregation works, but the result is a one row df, and the displayed row is only the `"tot"` one...is there an alternative way to make `prod` calcolous? I could see if it does the same even with a different code

Comment: I'm looking for a different way to calculate ratio between each df row and the tot row...seems that the problem comes from there... there are no typos 'cause in other functions I used`aggregate` with the same column values and everything worked perfectly

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, I created I new question, I apologize for my behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not too difficult to understand what you want to compute. But your original post was not produced in a reader-friendly mode; especially, not reproducible. I have edited in by careful reorganization, but found that I can not produce the error you put on there. The error I got is really `var1 is not found`.

Any way, the following code does what you expect:

```
VAL1 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "BB", "DD", "AA", "DD")
Num1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2) 
Num2 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4) 
Num3 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7) 
df <- data.frame(VAL1, Num1, Num2, Num3)
df1 <- df[,-1]
## you should not put df2 <- df1[1], but use df2 <- df[1]
## because variable names are stored in the 1st col of "df"
df2 <- df[1]
tot <- colSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)
prod <- df1 / rep(tot,each = nrow(df1))
df3 <- cbind(df2, prod)
## use "VAL1", not "val1", as this is the column name used in "df3"
## you can check column names by "colnames(df3)"
agg <- aggregate(. ~  VAL1, df3, sum)
```

The comment lines highlight the error/typos in your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here with the same error (`Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs,mf[-1L],FUN=FUN,...): no rows to aggregate.`) but the issue in my case was different.

My call was something like

```
df2 = aggregate(. ~ mycolname, data=df1, FUN=mean)
```

And the issue was that one of my columns contained only NA's. I solved the error by adding `na.action=na.pass` (which in my case was relevant).